# When a query is executed, what happens first in the back-end?

Tags: sql, performance, cognos, cognos-8

I'm having a query in **COGNOS** which would fetch me a huge volume of data. Since the execution time would be higher, I'd like to fine tune my query. Everyone knows that the WHERE clause in the query would get executed first.

My doubt is which would happen first when a query is executed?

The **JOIN** in the query would be established first or the **WHERE** clause would be executed first?

If JOIN is established first, I should specify the filters of the **DIMENSION** first else I should specify the filters of the **FACT** first.

Please explain me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Monitor your query on the database while it is running.  Get an explain plan and see what indexes it is using.  That will give you a clue as to if you need to change your criteria or joins.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of SQL is that it is a high level declarative language, meaning you tell it what results you want rather than how to get them. There are exceptions to this in various SQL implementations such as hints in Oracle to use a specific index etc, but as a general rule this holds true.

Behind the scenes the optimiser for your RDBMS implements relational algebra to do a cost based estimate of the different potential execution plans and select the one that it predicts will be the most efficient. The great thing about this is that you do not need to worry what order you write your where clauses in etc, so long as all of the information is there the optimiser should pick the most efficient plan.

That being said there are often things that you can so on the database to improve query performance such as building indexes on columns in large tables that are often used in filtering criteria or joins.

Another consideration is whether you can use parallel hints to speed up your run time but this will depend on your query, the execution plan that is being used, the RDBMS you are using and the hardware it is running on.

If you post the query syntax and what RDBMS you are using we can check if there is anything obvious that could be amended in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The order of filters definitely does not matter. The optimizer will take care of that.

As for filtering on the fact or dimension table - do you mean you are exposing the same field in your Cognos model for each (ex ProductID from both fact and Product dimension)? If so, that is not recommended. Generally speaking, you should expose the dimension field only.

This is more of a question about your SQL environment, though. I would export the SQL generated by Cognos from within Report Studio (Tools -> Show Generated SQL). From there, hopefully you are able to work with a good DBA to see if there are any obvious missing indexes, etc in your tables.

There's not a whole lot of options within Cognos to change the SQL generation. The prior poster mentions hints, which could work if writing native SQL, but that is a concept not known to Cognos. Really, all you can do is change the implict/explict join syntax which just controls whether the join happens in an ON statement or in the WHERE. Although the WHERE side is pretty ugly it generally compiles the same as ON.